# reST: inline links with arbitrary titles?

Tags: python, documentation, restructuredtext

If I've defined an internal hyperlink target, how can I link to it using arbitrary text as the link title?

For example:

```
_`This is a very long internal link target`.

...

A `short reference`_ to the very long link target.
```

How could I make the “short reference” target the “very long internal target”?

**Edit**: Another example:

```
Widgets
=======

...

Use a `widget`_.
```

How can I make “widget” (singular) link to the “Widgets” (plural) heading?

(of course, I realize that this could be done using `` `widget`_\s ``… But that doesn't solve the general problem)

Answer (score 4):

I haven't found a way to do this using "standard" reST. But with [Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/markup/inline.html#ref-role), the following works:

```
.. _`This is a very long internal link target`:

:ref:`Short reference <This is a very long internal link target>` to the very long link target.
```

Answer (score 2):

Nicely, [mzjn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5779964/1677912) also works for classes:

```
:class:`MyClasses <mymodule.MyClass>` in plural is awesome.
```

Hurray!

Answer (score 0):

A pure-reStructuredText method is to define multiple target names for the same target:

```
.. _my widget:
.. _above:
My long title about widgets
===========================
…
See how to use  `my widget`_ in the section above_.
```

(A limitation of this approach is that you may want to use the *same text* (e.g. "above") for *two different locations*, and the approach above fails in this case.)