# Sphinx: automatically label headings?

Tags: python-sphinx

In Sphinx, is it possible to automatically define labels for headings? I've found that my documents end up looking a lot like this:

```
.._doing stuff:

Doing Stuff
-----------

You might also want :ref:`other stuff`.

.._other stuff:

Other Stuff
-----------

No, you want :ref:`doing stuff`.
```

And it would be nice to remove that duplication.

Answer (score 3):

Within same document, you can always use the *traditional* reference:

```
Doing Stuff
-----------
You may want to try `Doing Stuff`_ -section again.
```

But as mentioned, this method does not work across the document files.

Comment: The problem with this is that the link text can't be changed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736476/rest-inline-links-with-arbitrary-titles

Answer (score 3):

Sphinx 1.4 added [`sphinx.ext.autosectionlabel`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/autosectionlabel.html) which supports this. It includes an option that will prefix the document name to the label to avoid cross-document clashes.